# ChartJS v2.6.0 unintended behaviour in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, chart.js

im running ChartJS v2.6 to generate a pieChart in a Bootstrap Grid. Everything gets displayed fine in Chrome/Firefox/.. but not in Internet Explorer, where the chart gets stretched in a unintended way on bigger screen sizes. Bootstrap should take care of the sizing. 
I cant figure out why so I thought about asking here if anybody can.
Is this a problem caused by CSS or ChartJS itself and how to fix it?

I uploaded the Webservice to a VPS because originally its hosted in a protected environment so please dont mind the wrong certificate.

https://116.203.26.254:8080/entry/5bebdf6d466f37f3000289e2

This is the element containing the Chart+Legend on the right side

```
    <div class="row" >
        <div id="charts" class="col-sm-7">
            <div id="chartWrapper" class="row">
                <canvas id="questionChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 correctAnswers" style="display: none"></div>

            <div class="col-12 answerTime">
                <div id="buttongrp"></div>
                <div id="answerCount"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="legendContainer" class="col-sm-5">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is how the Chart gets generated

```
            ctx = document.getElementById("questionChart");
            chart = new Chart(ctx, { //Die Optionen für das Diagramm unterscheiden sich wesentlich pro Fragetyp
                type: 'pie',
                data: {
                    labels: dataCountMap.keys(), //Generieren der Labels aus den Mapkeys
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: dataCountMap.values(), //Generieren der Diagrammdaten aus den Mapvalues
                        backgroundColor: usedColors, // Zufällig gewählte Farben aus dem in dem Optionen definierten Array
                        hoverBackgroundColor: usedHoverColors
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    showAllTooltips: true,
                    tooltips: {
                        callbacks: {
                            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
                                return value;
                            },
                            title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                return '';
                            }
                        },
                        tooltipTitleFontSize: 0,
                        bodyFontSize: 30,
                        displayColors: false,
                        xPadding: 10,
                        backgroundColor: '#323232'
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is the CSS scaling the Chart

```
        @media (max-width: 575px) {
        .pieChart {
            padding: 0px 60px 20px 60px;
        }
        .barChart {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px 40px 20px 40px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        .pieChart {
            padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
        }
        .barChart {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 860px) {
        .pieChart {
            padding: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
        }

        .barChart {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 861px) and (max-width: 991px) {
        .pieChart {
            padding: 0px 85px 0px 85px;
        }

        .barChart {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
        .pieChart {
            padding: 0px 110px 0px 110px;
        }
        .barChart {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1101px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
        .pieChart {
            padding: 0px 130px 0px 130px;
        }
        .barChart {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
        }
    }
```

This is in Chrome:
[image: This is in Chrome]

This is in IE:
[image: This is in IE]

Thanks

Comment: Post the code here, and with a screenshot of output if possible.

Comment: I tried to cut out the nessesary pieces from the code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code, I tested it with Bootstrap 4.1.3 and Bootstrap 3.3.7, always with ChartJS 2.6.0, on Internet Explorer 11 and the chart is always a perfect circle. Your problem is elsewhere and it is impossible to solve without seeing the whole thing in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following style(in style.css) is causing the issue

```
@media and (min-width:1200px) {
    .pieChart {
        padding: 0px 11vw 0 11vw;
    }
}
```

Please remove this style, it will fix the issue in IE.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats the solution.